# Angular8 Template Driven Form throwing error :TypeError: Cannot read property 'ProviderName' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

Tags: angular, typescript

The template driven from throwing error.

```
    ProviderComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ProviderName' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ProviderComponent.html:4)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:45259)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44271)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44565)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44278)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44565)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44278)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)

   (anonymous) @ main.js:1
    ProviderComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ProviderName' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ProviderComponent.html:4)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:45259)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44271)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44565)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44278)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44565)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44278)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
```

```
provider.component.html
```

```html
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-6">
            <input class="form-control" name="ProviderName"  #ProviderName="ngModel" 
          [(ngModel)]="providerService.selectedProvider.ProviderName" placeholder="Provider Name" 
           required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ProviderType" #ProviderType="ngModel" 
           [(ngModel)]="providerService.selectedProvider.ProviderType">
        </div>
    </div>
       
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info" 
             (click)="resetForm(employeeForm)">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

app.module.ts

```typescript
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { ProviderMainComponent } from './provider-main/provider-main.component';
    import { ProviderComponent } from './provider-main/provider/provider.component';
    import { ProviderListComponent } from './provider-main/provider-list/provider-list.component';
    import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ProviderMainComponent,
        ProviderComponent,
        ProviderListComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

proivder.service.ts:

```typescript
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    
    //Import the Provider Model
    import { Provider } from './provider.model';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    
    export class ProviderService {
      public selectedProvider:Provider; //Initialize the Provider Model
    
      constructor() { }
    }
```

provider.component.ts:

```typescript
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ProviderService } from '../shared/provider.service'; //1.Import the ProviderService
    import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-provider',
      templateUrl: './provider.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./provider.component.css'],
    
    })
    
    export class ProviderComponent implements OnInit { 
      //3.Inject the ProviderService
      constructor(private providerService:ProviderService) { 
    
      }
    
      ngOnInit() {
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add ‘?’ in the template since selectedProvider is undefined in some point of time.

providerService.selectedProvider?.ProviderName

Angular tries to resolve this property during binding validation in change detection but it hits this null exception. ? Operator is a null safety operator.

Comment: In case you're not sure what the Elvis Operator (?) is or how it is used, please refer to https://www.joshmorony.com/safely-displaying-data-with-the-elvis-operator/. 

Additionally, while this is a valid solution, it should also be mentioned that it's best practice to have a loading state built into the component in which the component has time to properly initialise their variables - usually indicated by some sort of loading animation.

Comment: I end up with the below error after applying Elvis(?) operator (providerService.selectedProvider?.ProviderName)
Uncaught Error: 
Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 48 in [providerService.selectedProvider?.ProviderName=$event] in ng:///AppModule/ProviderComponent.html

Comment: Later I initialized the providerService.selectedProvider with empty values inside the provider component constructer , it worked. With Elvis operator it is not working. It throws different error.
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 48 in [providerService.selectedProvider?.ProviderName=$event] in ng:///AppModule/ProviderComponent.html